# Magento 2.4.5: How to display custom information in admin panel's order details screen for a custom payment method

Tags: magento2.4.5, additional-information

I would like to display some additional information of a transaction in the admin panel's order details screen (Sales > Order > click "view" on whatever order) for a custom payment method I am developing to integrate with a payment gateway. I made the custom payment method to create a new custom table in the database upon installation.

What I want the custom payment method to do:

- Additional information are obtained from the response sent back from the payment gateway after a transaction is completed, and will be stored into the custom table
- Query the additional information from the custom table of the selected order and display them under the "Payment and Shipping Method" section in the order details screen.

[image]

Red box is where I want the information to be display at. Please help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pull the information by extending Payment Method Block.

**registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    '[VendorName]_[ModuleName]',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Info.php**

```
<?php

namespace [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab;

class Info extends  \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Info{



}
```

**etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Info" type="[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Info" />
</config>
```

**view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_tab_info">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" translate="true" xsi:type="string">order/view/tab/Info.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/tab/Info.phtml**

```
    <?php
    /**
     * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    
    // @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
    
    ?>
    <?php /** @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Info */ ?>
    <?php $_order = $block->getOrder() ?>
    
    <div id="order-messages">
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('order_messages') ?>
    </div>
    
    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('order_info') ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_order->getId() ?>"/>
    
    <section class="admin__page-section order-view-billing-shipping">
        <div class="admin__page-section-title">
            <span class="title"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Payment &amp; Shipping Method') ?></span>
        </div>
<!-- this is Sample Text -->
        <h1>Magento 2 Custom Payment Text</h1>
        <div class="admin__page-section-content">
            <div class="admin__page-section-item order-payment-method<?php if ($_order->getIsVirtual()): ?> order-payment-method-virtual<?php endif; ?>">
                <?php /* Payment Method */ ?>
                <div class="admin__page-section-item-title">
                    <span class="title"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Payment Information') ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="admin__page-section-item-content">
                    <div class="order-payment-method-title"><?php echo $block->getPaymentHtml() ?></div>
                    <div class="order-payment-currency"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('The order was placed using %1.', $_order->getOrderCurrencyCode()) ?></div>
                    <div class="order-payment-additional">
                        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('order_payment_additional'); ?>
                        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('payment_additional_info'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('order_shipping_view') ?>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <?php echo $block->getGiftOptionsHtml() ?>
    
    <section class="admin__page-section">
        <div class="admin__page-section-title">
            <span class="title"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Items Ordered') ?></span>
        </div>
        <?php echo $block->getItemsHtml() ?>
    </section>
    
    <section class="admin__page-section">
        <div class="admin__page-section-title">
            <span class="title"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Order Total') ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="admin__page-section-content">
            <div class="admin__page-section-item order-comments-history">
                <div class="admin__page-section-item-title">
                    <span class="title"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Notes for this Order') ?></span>
                </div>
                <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('order_history') ?>
            </div>
    
            <div class="admin__page-section-item order-totals">
                <div class="admin__page-section-item-title">
                    <span class="title"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Order Totals') ?></span>
                </div>
                <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('order_totals') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('popup_window');?>
    
    <script>
        require([
            "prototype",
            "Magento_Sales/order/giftoptions_tooltip"
        ], function(){
    
    //<![CDATA[
            /**
             * Retrieve gift options tooltip content
             */
            function getGiftOptionsTooltipContent(itemId) {
                var contentLines = [];
                var headerLine = null;
                var contentLine = null;
    
                $$('#gift_options_data_' + itemId + ' .gift-options-tooltip-content').each(function (element) {
                    if (element.down(0)) {
                        headerLine = element.down(0).innerHTML;
                        contentLine = element.down(0).next().innerHTML;
                        if (contentLine.length > 30) {
                            contentLine = contentLine.slice(0,30) + '...';
                        }
                        contentLines.push(headerLine + ' ' + contentLine);
                    }
                });
                return contentLines.join('<br/>');
            }
            giftOptionsTooltip.setTooltipContentLoaderFunction(getGiftOptionsTooltipContent);
            window.getGiftOptionsTooltipContent = getGiftOptionsTooltipContent;
    //]]>
    
        });
    </script>
```

By this way you can override the Payment Section.